# use if condition with selected option of an HTML Select element

Tags: php, html, view, laravel-5, laravel-blade

```
  <select name="test">
    <option value="a">test a</option>
    <option value="b">test b</option>
    <option value="c">test c</option>
  </select>
```

I want when option = a for example then have another select elements how should I use variable "test" in if condition,

In other way I want this but I dont know which syntax is good for me (I use blade , laravel-5)

```
 <select name="test">
    <option value="a">test a</option>
    <option value="b">test b</option>
    <option value="c">test c</option>
  </select>

 @if("test" = "b")
 <select name="test2">
    <option value="1">test a</option>
    <option value="2">test b</option>
    <option value="3">test c</option>
  </select>
  @endif
```

Comment: Did you tried something to achieve this ?

Comment: nope:D @raveenanigam

Comment: Have a try. If some error occured i will help u.

Comment: @raveenanigam I am a beginner

Comment: I tried  @if("test" = "b")

Comment: @var $test = "test" , @if($test = 'b') –

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I recommend to use the `<optgroup>` [HTML-Tag](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/HTML/Element/optgroup), because it is very well supported and does not need PHP, JS, etc.

```
<select>
  <optgroup label="Group 1">
    <option>Option 1.1</option>
  </optgroup> 
  <optgroup label="Group 2">
    <option>Option 2.1</option>
    <option>Option 2.2</option>
  </optgroup>
  <optgroup label="Group 3">
    <option>Option 3.1</option>
    <option>Option 3.2</option>
    <option>Option 3.3</option>
  </optgroup>
</select>
```